# Ubuntu 20.04LTS: Grub OS selection menu shows up on restart but not on power on

Tags: grub2, uefi, startup, reboot

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop with Windows 10 dusl boot. I have Windows Fast Start-Up disabled.

I am observing a picuiar behaviour, when I power on my machine I never see the grub menu, however, whenever I restart my machine, I am prompted with the OS selection menu. On power on, my screen waits on a blank screen for `GRUB_TIMEOUT` seconds and then starts `GRUB_DEFAULT` and if I press  on the blank screen the `GRUB_DEFAULT` OS starts booting.

Cn anyone suggest how can I set GRUB to prompt the GRUB minu every time either power on or reboot.

Comment: Is grub on the internal hard drive?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 internal SSDs. HD0: SATA |||, HD1: mSATA. Both of my OS' are on HD1: mSATA SSD.

Answer (score 1):

With 18.04 or later to always see menu, change grub setting & update grub menu with new setting.

```
sudo nano -B /etc/default/grub

#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu

sudo update-grub
```

You may also have UEFI fast boot on, which assumes no system changes & immediately reboots. That is different than Windows fast start up.

Note that grub only boots working Windows. If Windows update turns fast start up back on, you have to directly boot Windows from UEFI, not grub. Or you may need your Windows repair/recovery flash drive to fix Windows. Always have both Windows repair/recovery and Ubuntu live installer for current versions of installed operating systems.

Comment: You forgot to mention the `GRUB_TIMEOUT=5`, I think it is named, for a 5 second delay when starting from the GRUB screen. To give a time to actually pick something with it, when set to the default 0 it will just boot without getting any chance to select an option, wasting the effort of turning on the menu.

Comment: I have Windows 10 installed and rechecked for Fast Start-up, and it is disabled still. Also, I barely boot into windows, most of the time I just start Ubuntu.  BTW, I tried chanding GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu and `update-grub` and nothing changed. When I start ubuntu from firmware menu directly, still I don't see the GRUB minu...

Comment: I never suggest 0 as then you can never get a grub menu. I change to 3, but have to be quick if I want to boot one of my other installs. Default is 10 and that is good for most.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried the GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu and that didn't resolve it. I have turned off fast boot. Anyone have anything else that works? It also seems to me that my motherboard splash screen doesn't show anymore either on power up (it does, as does grub, upon restart however).