# Grub no show with dual boot Ubuntu studio 20.10 install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, thinkpad

The objective is to set up a dual boot laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

Am struggling to get Grub to show at all on startup on my Thinkpad laptop. I can install Ubuntu from USB which of course shows Grub but don't get a Grub menu at all from a restart when Ubuntu is installed and booting on the HDD. So, can't boot into Windows, it just goes into Ubuntu. I've done a boot-repair and uninstalled and reinstalled Ubuntu (back to Windows boot) and yet another boot-repair but still no joy, and I set the display period to 30 seconds for Grub for the last attempt with boot-repair. I've turned off secure boot as well but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

From reading the threads on here, looks like dual boot either works or doesn't at all on Thinkpads? Of course, I could be doing something amazingly stupid, so welcome any suggestions! I can boot into Windows if I go into the BIOS and change the boot order to the Windows launcher but it is a bit of a pain to have to do that if Grub actually worked, and I could choose the OS on startup....

Latest Pastebin is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XyHNpCw9px/)

thanks in advance!!

Comment: What model Lenovo? Have you updated UEFI & if SSD, updated SSD firmware? Some other Lenovo: Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Extreme 2019 UEFI settings required.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291280/after-running-boot-repair-and-disabeling-secure-boot-still-not-booting-to-grub & https://www.cnet.com/news/is-your-thinkpads-usb-c-port-not-working-upgrade-its-firmware/

Comment: thanks @oldfred. that particular link you posted isn't really the same issue as mine. To be honest, what seems to be happening is that when I boot, I get a blank screen and a delay for 30 seconds or so, but I think that Grub is running, it just isn't visible. I need to experiment more to see if I press the down arrow I can get it to boot into Windows. Where can I check what should be in the Grub menu> I assume the cfg file... BTW it is a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga S12, if that makes any difference.

Comment: UEFI boot menu should directly boot you into Windows. And with UEFI, you have to press escape right after logo but before menu. If UEFI fast boot on, you may not have time to press any key. Then full "cold" boot from total power down & drain system may work, but still have to press key quickly. https://www.cnet.com/news/is-your-thinkpads-usb-c-port-not-working-upgrade-its-firmware/

Comment: okay, I,m not having a problem with UEFI, I'm having a problem with Grub menu not showing up when I'm starting up Ubuntu. If I want to boot into Windows, I can just change the boot order of the volumes, and then Windows boots no problem. The only bad thing about this is that I have to go into the BIOS to change that when I want to boot into a different OS. If Grub showed up when I booted Ubuntu... then I could maybe choose the OS every time I restarted..

Comment: Is Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? UEFI and BIOS/Legacy are not compatible. If grub started in BIOS mode, it cannot boot Windows. Also grub only boots working Windows, which also means it cannot be hibernated/fast start up on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation If not run this report: Copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report (do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: yes, its in UEFI mode and both windows and ubuntu start up just fine. Grub doesn't show when booting into Ubuntu. So, no problems with BIOS, fast startup, Windows, Ubuntu, UEFI etc, just not seeing Grub at all as part of the startup sequence for Ubuntu. As nobody has any idea why Grub isn't displaying I'll rebuild with LTS as I need that to fix a dependency issue with Citrix, then return to seeing if this issue still exists,

Comment: Have you run `sudo update-grub` If grub menu has Windows is should show. You also can edit grub settings to always show menu. details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319810/ubuntu-20-04lts-grub-os-selection-menu-shows-up-on-restart-but-not-on-power-on

Comment: Have reinstalled windows, got windows to fit in a small partition and then  then installed Kubuntu 20.04 LTS in the spare space. Kubuntu refused to install 'alongside' Windows, it doesn't like it for some reason, and never gives me the option in the installer. Still have exactly the same issue.. no grub menu showing up at any point, but working Windows and Ubuntu installations. Bit of a shame, but I guess I'll live with it, even if it is a bit cumbersome to go into the BIOS every time to switch between OS, at least I have both on one system. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like either not really UEFI installs, or Windows has hibernated flag set which may be from fast start up. Windows turns fast start up back on with updates, so may still be an issue.