# Windows 10 and Kubuntu dual boot...no Grub menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

I had Windows 10 alongside Fedora linux in dual boot, and that worked just fine. I wanted to switch from Fedora to Kubuntu, and installed it over Fedora (deleted previous partitions, and created new ones from free space), and that installed just fine. But, I've lost grub menu. After doing almost everything, I've managed to repair it via Boot repair tool in Kubuntu. But I still don't get the grub menu until I go to Bios and change something in boot device priority. Anything. I can select ubuntu as the first booting device, or my ssd (I guess that's Windows)m it's doesn't matter, I will get the grub menu. But when I load an OS, Windows 10 or Kubuntu, after a restart the grub menu will be lost. Until I go back to Bios again and change something in that order.

Plus, you can see that I still have Fedora in bios for some reason. I don't know how to remove that.

Any ideas how to make the grub permanent?

EDIT:
Output of the sudo efibootmgr -v command:

```
marjan@MyKubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 15 seconds
BootOrder: 0008,0005,000C,0003,0007,0006,0009
Boot0000  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0001  Boot Menu     FvFile(86488440-41bb-42c7-93ac-450fbf7766bf)
Boot0002  Recovery      FvFile(ab4579c4-3bc5-4489-a88e-0f21e6cebf85)
Boot0003* SATA CD:      VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a354)
Boot0004* CD-ROM:       VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,be9d0102e211f3489efa0b983c96839b)
Boot0005* SATA HDD:     VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot0006* USB CD:       VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0007* USB FDD:      VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot0008* USB HDD:      VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot0009* NETWORK:      VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot000A* Windows Boot Manager  HD(5,GPT,ec6db701-0ed6-4916-b850-dc359cb8f9f4,0x18c2a000,0xf4000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...br...............
Boot000C* ubuntu        HD(5,GPT,ec6db701-0ed6-4916-b850-dc359cb8f9f4,0x18c2a000,0xf4000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
marjan@MyKubuntu:~$
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What brand/model system? HP often needs boot order changed in UEFI settings, not UEFI menu. Grub is turning off os-prober for some security reason. You can temporarily turn os-prober back on & update-grub. Or copy boot stanza into 40_custom. You can use efibootmgr to remove UEFI boot entries & should remove the /EFI/fedora folder in the ESP - efi system partition. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2469993 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/659528/grub-menu-with-windows-10-and-ubuntu-14-04/659910#659910

Comment: Samsung. I don't know the exact model.

Comment: If you always want grub menu to show, you can edit /etc/default/grub and change to menu. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319810/ubuntu-20-04lts-grub-os-selection-menu-shows-up-on-restart-but-not-on-power-on

Comment: It's already set to =menu. Also os-prober is set to =false.

Comment: OK, I think I maybe know what the issue is. Still don't know the solution. I think the grub menu is there, but the monitor doesn't display it. The backlight is on, but the grub menu, or anything on the display is not there. I tested it by setting the timeout to 30 seconds, and then I counted the time and the display is on for 30 seconds before it starts to load the default OS. Tried changing the time to 10 seconds, and after 10 seconds it started loading the default OS. So, for some reason, it doesn't show what's on the screen, only the backlight.

Comment: When I add GRUB_VIDEO_BACKEND=vga to grub, I can then press 'c' key while the countdown is going, and with ESC key I can get to the grub. Weird.

Comment: a) If you type `exit` at the Grub prompt, do you then boot to Kubuntu or Windows?

b) In Kubuntu, open a terminal, run `efibootmgr -v`, and add the output to your question. (This prints information about your Boot Menu - see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/efibootmgr.8.html ). 

c) Are you using Kubuntu 20.04 LTS or 22.10?

Comment: Added the output to my question. BTW, when I shutdown my laptop and start it again, I get the grub menu, no issues. But when I reset it, no grub menu.

Comment: https://youtu.be/i4wgpJTgeKQ

Comment: https://youtu.be/HJn99TiDjCc

Comment: You can try to change UEFI boot order with efibootmgr -o command. Some systems only work if you change from within UEFI settings. With UEFI you should always be able to press escape just after vendor screen, but before grub menu should appear. Sometimes have to try several times to get it to work as timing is short. I remove quiet spash in grub linux line to see loading process. That is also in  log files. https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr