Grub menu doesn't show any longer
Since yesterday, my grub boot menu doesn't show any longer. 24.4.1.
The PC boots straight into kubuntu. The Partition should be there, however, since
sudo update-grub shows:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic
Found memtest86+x64 image: /memtest86+x64.bin
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda1
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

Also at cold boot, no menu shows. The data in the W10-partitions seem to be there, I can mount them and read them.
What to do?

I suspect you have changed /etc/default/grub

With 18.04 or later to always see menu
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319810/ubuntu-20-04lts-grub-os-selection-menu-shows-up-on-restart-but-not-on-power-on &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time/16049#16049

6,7c6
< GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
< GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
---
> GRUB_DEFAULT=0

I changed to save the last successful boot., otherwise I purposely selected the "installation of the maintainer" during release upgrade 22.04 to 24.04.1

For an UEFI system (which yours is) you can get the grub menu to show by pressing ESC during boot. (For a standard install you must be running grub as its an integral part of the boot process.)
I suspect you have changed /boot/grub/grub.cfg in the past and it has got updated as is built automatically from within ubuntu
Files in `/etc/default/grub` & `/etc/grub.d/XX_XXXX` -->> /boot/grub/grub.cfg 

To get the grub menu to show by default you need to update either one of the first two.
In /etc/default/grub make the change
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden  #  hidden --> menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0 #  0 --> 10

In /etc/grub.d/ an example would be /etc/grub.d/30-os_prober
At line 337: -
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "\${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10

I think this is the default?
You have enabled this to boot WIN10.
If this is so then the grub compiler grub-mkconfig used to create /boot/grub/grub.cfg could possibly be crashing before getting to it. Have you modified any of the files in this directory /etc/grub.d I wonder?
I hope some of this helps

Yes, @david, it did.
Though I don't really understand what had happened. The GRUB_TIMEOUT has always been 10, in order to select the other OS. No, never changed any file in there.
Though once the GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE was set to menu, the menu actually appeared after a reboot.
And no other changes on my side than those indicated in my comment above.
Thanks a bunch!

Read up on this a bit more, and https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Konfiguration/ "Die Einstellung hidden bzw. countdown wird ignoriert und das GRUB-Menü immer angezeigt, wenn mehr als ein Betriebssystem von GRUB verwaltet wird." (With more than one OSes being bootable through grub, the setting 'hidden' will be ignored).
Has anything changed within grub?

The above comment in English: "The hidden or countdown setting is ignored and the GRUB menu is always displayed when more than one operating system is managed by GRUB." (With more than one OSes being bootable through grub, the setting 'hidden' will be ignored). Has anything changed within grub
